# vsetdiff for every pair in two columns

Tags: string, match

I've seen that to count the number of different words in two strings (s1 and s2) you can use:

```
length(vsetdiff(unlist(strsplit(s1," ")),unlist(strsplit(s2," "))))
```

If I have two columns of strings, how could I efficiently calculate the number of different words between every pair of strings between the two columns. For example, using the following dummy columns:

```
a=as.data.frame(c("Insurance broker","Phone Operator","real estate agent","child care worker"))

colnames(a)=c("Occupation")

b=as.data.frame(c("Broker","Dog walker","health care coordinator"))

colnames(b)=c("Job")
```

I would like to count the number of different words between every pair of entries in the Occupation and Job columns

Edit:

To clarify:

I want some matrix (ie 4x3 or 3x4) that counts the differences between

Insurance broker and Broker

Insurance broker and Dog walker

Insurance broker and health care coordinator

...

Child care worker and health care coordinator

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
l_1 = unlist(str_split(a$Occupation, " "))
l_2 = unlist(str_split(b$Job, " "))
> sum(!l_1 %in% l_2)
[1] 9
> sum(!l_2 %in% l_1)
[1] 5
> l_1[l_1 %in% l_2]
[1] "care"
> l_2[l_2 %in% l_1]
[1] "care"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.